# Cycle through lists based on different list?

Tags: python, list, iteration

I want to cycle through my first list `c` based on my second list `changes`.

What I would like to see as a result is:

```
60, 71, 62, 69, 64, 71, 64, 67.
```

Currently, it just prints the list `c`. My real list for `changes` has 64 numbers in total.

For context the list `c` is the midi values for the C maj scale.

How can I achieve this? I'm sure it's simple.

```
C = [60, 62, 64, 65, 67, 69, 71]

changes = [0, 6, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2]

for notes in C:
    print(notes)
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the output you want? The third element of `changes` is `2`, and `C[2]` is `64`. Why do you expect `62` instead of `64` as the third element of your output?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
C = [60, 62, 64, 65, 67, 69, 71]
changes = [0, 6, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2]

output = []
idx_current = 0
for x in changes:
    idx_current = (idx_current + x) % len(C)
    output.append(C[idx_current])

print(output) # [60, 71, 62, 69, 64, 71, 64, 67]
```

Based on your output, I guess you want to increase the index of `C` while wrapping around if necessary. This is done in the line `idx = (idx + d) % len(C)`, i.e., increase the index modulo `len(C)`.

Alternatively, using [Assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) for Python 3.8+, you can do (with the same idea)

```py
idx_cur = 0
idx = [idx_cur := (idx_cur + x) % len(C) for x in changes]
output = [C[i] for i in idx]
```

Comment: Ah, that's what it is! I was wondering how OP gets that output from those indices.

Comment: Thankyou, the index is what I needed!